# SQL Server : string replace for variable length

Tags: sql, sql-server

Scenario: column contains numbers as ('1234', '123', '23456') - I need to replace the first number with 'A' and replace the remaining numbers with `*`.

Output should be:

```
A***
A**
A****
```

Can anyone help me? How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If `('1234', '123', '23456')` is literally the value in a single record/column, then it would be very difficult to do this with basic SQL Server.  Why isn't your data normalized?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Is this homework?

Comment: `'1234', '123', '23456'`  is this a single column value or 3 Rows in your table??

Comment: I tried below. select concat('A',str1) as New_String from (select substr(colname,2,length(colname)) str1 from tablename);

Comment: its a 3 different rows in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
Drop Table #MyTempTable

Create Table #MyTempTable (
    NAME NVARCHAR(100)
);

Insert Into #MyTempTable VALUES ('3243')
Insert Into #MyTempTable VALUES ('123')
Insert Into #MyTempTable VALUES ('432423')
Insert Into #MyTempTable VALUES ('423')
Insert Into #MyTempTable VALUES ('432')

select * from #MyTempTable

Update #MyTempTable 
SET NAME = 'A' + REPLICATE('*', len(NAME) - 1)

select * from #MyTempTable
```

You should use [replicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command.

> *Replicate*- Repeats a string value a specified number of times.

Before update command,

```
NAME
3243
123
432423
423
432
```

After Update command,

```
NAME
A***
A**
A*****
A**
A**
```

Answer (score 3):

`REPLICATE` is best option for you.

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB(VAL VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #TAB 
VALUES ('1234'), ('123'), ('23456')


SELECT 'A'+REPLICATE('*', LEN(VAL)-1)  FROM #TAB
```

Comment: Same answer of me :)

Comment: be carefull to null value or value with len <= 1

Comment: Thanks for pointing. And I started writing answer on own. @Esperento57

Comment: your example dont bug with null value or len <=1, it give null as result. but is that what he wants as a result...

Comment: Thanks all I used the replicate and it works as expected. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
drop TABLE #TestTable
CREATE TABLE #TestTable (val varchar(500));

INSERT INTO #TestTable (val)
VALUES ('123'), ('23456'), ('1234555');

select case when len(isnull(val, ''))<2 then 'A' else 'A' + REPLICATE('*', len(val) - 1) end 
from #TestTable
```